# Use '.' and ',' as a number separator in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

In the Google Sheet opened in browser I have to use `,` separator in the digit. If I put `.` as separator like `2.10` this is considered as text and all formulas fail.

Is it possible to configure to have **both** `,` and `.` as a number separator?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't think a solution exist, but how about the following workaround.

You can adjust your current formulas and replace `.` with `,` which is the valid format for the numbers in your spreadsheet:

`=(SUBSTITUTE(A1,".",",")+1)`

**Example:**

In my case I use `.` as a separator, so I can substitute `,` with `.`:

[image]

**Summing a range of cells:**

`=SUM(ARRAYFORMULA(VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(A1:A;".";","))))`

[image]

Comment: This can be a workaround in some cases, thanks. I need to sum up those values and the range like this doesn't work `=SUM(SUBSTITUTE(A1;".";","):SUBSTITUTE(A100;".";","))`

Comment: @Vitalii Thanks for your feedback. Check my updated answer.